# Error in command line "The system cannot find the path specified."

Tags: windows-7, command-line, cmd.exe

Not sure what I did but since past 5 weeks but I am getting this error `The system cannot find the path specified.` when I run any command or start cmd. Here is what I get when I start command line:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users\Jason>
```

How do I troubleshoot this error?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try the following.

1. Open the Registry Editor (press <kbd>[image]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type `regedit` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>) .
2. Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun` and clear the values.
3. Also check `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun`.

<sub>[Source](http://carol-nichols.com/2011/03/17/the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified/)</sub>

Comment: Also look at  HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment for the ComSpec

Comment: Any other tricks? I get the same issue, but don't have AutoRun under Command Processor?

Comment: Same here, neither paths have "AutoRun"

Comment: Same here, no AutoRun entry, but same error as the original poster.

Comment: If finally found an AutoRun entry (from a removed Anaconda installation) under quite "exotic" key":  
Computer\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-1022529333-140522832-1157387970-3781\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor 
This only showed up as the third or fourth hit while searching for "Command Processor" (in Keys). 
Which means you probably need to fiddle around a bit to be successful.

Comment: Thank you!! I had the same problem

Answer (score 3):

Your Path must be wrong. The issue is that your command prompt can't find any programs to match what you're entering.

- From your desktop, rick-click "My Computer" and click "Properties"
- In the System Properties window, click on the Advanced tab.
- In the Advanced section, click the Environment Variables button.
- In the Environment Variables window , highlight the Path variable in the Systems Variable section and click the Edit button.

I don't know the default PATH values you need, but I am willing to bet you have something that isn't right. Post what you have here.

Comment: There were couple of invalid paths. I removed them, rebooted but still getting same error. I checked Path for my username and also system.

Comment: Same issue .. if I run CMD (as admin) no error. 
If I run a cmd as "normal" user I also get this error whenever invoking "CMD" 
And I can quite surely exclude the PATH being messed up - since in order to test this I just deleted every entry in it and the error STILL pops up.